# mix release crashing with exception

Tags: erlang, elixir, travis-ci, exrm

Setting up a new build/release process that uses Travis CI. When I try to create the release after tests pass I am getting a crash.

Command:

`mix release --verbosity=verbose`

Error:

```
===> Provider successfully run: resolve_release
===> Running provider release
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :enoent}
        src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:224: :rlx_prv_assembler.rewrite_app_file/2
        (stdlib) lists.erl:1238: :lists.map/2
        src/ec_plists.erl:753: anonymous fn/3 in :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:900: :ec_plists.handle_error/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:764: :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:161: :rlx_prv_assembler.copy_app_directories_to_output/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:59: :rlx_prv_assembler.do/1
    src/relx.erl:308: :relx.run_provider/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1262: :lists.foldl/3
    src/relx.erl:291: :relx.run_providers_for_actions/2
    lib/exrm/utils.ex:103: ReleaseManager.Utils.relx/5
18:03:06.402 [error] Process #PID<0.13561.0> raised an exception
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :enoent}
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:224: :rlx_prv_assembler.rewrite_app_file/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1238: :lists.map/2
    src/ec_plists.erl:753: anonymous fn/3 in :ec_plists.local_runmany/3    ===> Provider successfully run: resolve_release
===> Running provider release
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :enoent}
        src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:224: :rlx_prv_assembler.rewrite_app_file/2
        (stdlib) lists.erl:1238: :lists.map/2
        src/ec_plists.erl:753: anonymous fn/3 in :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:900: :ec_plists.handle_error/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:764: :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:161: :rlx_prv_assembler.copy_app_directories_to_output/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:59: :rlx_prv_assembler.do/1
    src/relx.erl:308: :relx.run_provider/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1262: :lists.foldl/3
    src/relx.erl:291: :relx.run_providers_for_actions/2
    lib/exrm/utils.ex:103: ReleaseManager.Utils.relx/5
18:03:06.402 [error] Process #PID<0.13561.0> raised an exception
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :enoent}
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:224: :rlx_prv_assembler.rewrite_app_file/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1238: :lists.map/2
    src/ec_plists.erl:753: anonymous fn/3 in :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
```

This is running Elixir 1.2.2 and OTP 18.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.02

Could this be an issue with the install of OTP?

**EDIT**

Was missing exrm from the applications list in `mix.exs`. Added it there and now this is the error:

```
===> Provider successfully run: app_discover
===> Running provider resolve_release
===> Solving Release cymbal-0.0.1
===> Provider (resolve_release) failed with: {error,
                                                 {rlx_prv_release,
                                                  {failed_solve,
                                                   {unreachable_package,
                                                    ssl_verify_fun}}}}
==> ERROR: "Unable to find application ssl_verify_fun. See the debug output for more information."
```

Comment: When I had this kind of problem it was related with the version of libraries. Check if the deps versions are the same in your machine and in the CI machine.

Comment: @migore how do I check that? The mix.lock file hasn't changed so I imagine everything should remain the same regardless of where it runs. It also is passing all the tests so I'd imagine it is pulling down the right libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling in a release (`rel`) directory to add the new release to before deploying. That directory was not formatted correctly so when `exrm` went to add a new release it couldn't find what it was looking for and crashed.
If you are having this issue try starting with a fresh `rel` dir to see if that fixes the issue.